# WPF Adding an Image Control Dynamically to a Dynamically Built Grid

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, vb.net-2010

I have a Grid control I am building dynamically.

I am trying to add some other controls to it, my TextBlock displays fine, but the Image does not.

Yes, the image source is a valid BitmapImage.  CompanyDetails is populated correctly.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CreateItemContent(ByVal _Item As CompanyTyping.List, ByVal _TV As RadTileView)
    Dim _Det = Company.CompanyDetails(_Item.CompanyID)
    Dim item As New RadTileViewItem()
    'create and define the inner grid
    Dim _PG As New Grid()
    Dim gridCol1 As New ColumnDefinition()
    gridCol1.Width = New GridLength(200)
    Dim gridCol2 As New ColumnDefinition()
    gridCol2.Width = New GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star)
    _PG.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol1)
    _PG.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol2)
    'add the initial items to the initial grid
    Dim _Img As New Image()
    _Img.VerticalAlignment = Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top
    _Img.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
    _Img.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
    _Img.MinHeight = 50
    _Img.MinWidth = 200
    _Img.Source = ByteArrayToImage(_Det(0).Logo)
    Grid.SetColumn(_Img, 1)
    _PG.Children.Add(_Img)
    Dim _PGI As New Grid()
    Dim gridRow1 As New RowDefinition()
    gridRow1.Height = New GridLength(29)
    Dim gridRow2 As New RowDefinition()
    gridRow2.Height = New GridLength(29)
    Dim gridRow3 As New RowDefinition()
    gridRow3.Height = New GridLength(29)
    Dim gridRow4 As New RowDefinition()
    gridRow4.Height = New GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star)
    _PGI.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow1)
    _PGI.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow2)
    _PGI.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow3)
    _PGI.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow4)
    Grid.SetColumn(_PGI, 0)
    _PG.Children.Add(_PGI)
    Dim _TB1 As New TextBlock()
    _TB1.Text = _Item.MainContact
    Grid.SetRow(_TB1, 0)
    _PGI.Children.Add(_TB1)


    item.Header = _Item.Name & " - ID: " & _Item.CompanyID
    _TV.Items.Add(item)
    item.SetValue(RadTileViewItem.ContentProperty, _PG)
End Sub
```

And ByteArrayToImage:

```
Public Function ByteArrayToImage(_Bytes As Byte()) As System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
    If _Bytes Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Dim _bm As New BitmapImage()
        Using _strm As New MemoryStream(_Bytes)
            With _bm
                .BeginInit()
                .CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
                .StreamSource = _strm
                .EndInit()
            End With
        End Using
        Return _bm
    End If
End Function
```

I have verified, that in a full XAML version of this, the Image control's source is showing the image correctly...   just not in here

Comment: the image is being stored as a byte array in a sql database

Comment: on top of that, WPF does not support using a straight out Image or Bitmap for use in an image control's source, hence the need to then convert to a BitmapImage which is supported

Comment: WPF provides all kinds of direct conversions from byte array to ImageSource. In fact you are already using one by setting the StreamSource of a BitmapImage. What exactly is contained in your byte array? Is it a raw pixel buffer or an encoded image like JPEG or PNG?

Comment: Just an image, like jpeg or PNG.  I did alot of searching, and everything I found states in order to get the correct byta array back from SQL, and then convert it to a usable Image Control source that I have to do what is posted.

Comment: See my non-answer for how to decode an image in WPF.

Comment: I am a complete tool!   This line: `gridCol2.Width = New GridLength(, GridUnitType.Star)`  was the culprit, once I changed it to `gridCol2.Width = New GridLength(500, GridUnitType.Star)` the image displayed just fine.    So, if you can tell me how to set a dynamic width of a grid column in the code behind, you'll get the accept

Comment: `new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto)` would set the column width to automatically adjust to the image width.

Comment: aye :)   can you edit your answer and include it so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that setting

```
gridCol2.Width = New GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto)
```

would make the image appear as expected.

---

Just to show some code how you would create a BitmapImage from a byte array that contains an encoded image buffer, e.g. a JPEG or PNG. Sorry that this is C#, but i don't speak VB. It should however easily be translated to VB.

```
byte[] buffer = ...
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer)) // create stream from buffer
{
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; // necessary as stream is closed after EndInit
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
}
// stream is closed by leaving the using block
```

With no VB knowlegde at all I'd translate that as follows:

```
Dim stream As New MemoryStream(buffer)
Dim bitmapImage As New BitmapImage()
bitmapImage.BeginInit()
bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream
bitmapImage.EndInit()
stream.Close()
```

Comment: thanks for this Clemens, i'm sure it'll help clean up my code ;)  I'll be back after I test to see if it cures the issue in the question though...   (no probs, I can convert ;))

Comment: ok, I updated the question with the new code, and verified that with a normal Image control in XAML I am able to set the source from the db...    however, this does not answer the question